# How to add software sources for dom0 in Qubes

Tags: yum, qubes

I would like to install some customization packages to Qubes KDE. Is there any way to temporarily override yum config to add another repository?

Answer (score 1):

Example repo

```
http://repo.download.org/new.repo
```

Manually create new repo file in dom0 terminal

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
sudo nano <new>.repo
```

Then open example repo URL and place its contents to your `<new>.repo`

```
[new]
name = New Example Repo
type = rpm-md
baseurl = http://repo.download.org/new/fedora_23/
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = http://repo.download.org/new/fedora_23/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled = 1
```

> Keep in mind that adding repos to dom0 is SECURITY RISK.

Press `Ctrl+O` to save as new file and `Ctrl+X` to exit nano editor. Then update repo cache by

```
sudo qubes-dom0-update
```

Now installing packages is as simple as `sudo qubes-dom0-update <package>`